# 4 equations with 4 unknowns

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I have reduced a problem I'm trying to solve, to the following $4$ equations:

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{A}{b+c}$$
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{D-e}{b-c}$$
$$\sin(\theta) = \frac{c}{e}$$
$$\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 = 1$$
where only $A$ and $D$ are known.

I having a hard time solving this analytically. Is there an analytic solution to these equations or can a solution only be found numerically? Is there a(n) (easy) way to tell whether it is one or the other?

Comment: You only have 2 equations... The last equation is always satisfied and $\theta$ can be eliminated. In the end you just have $\frac ce = \frac{D-e}{b-c}$ and $\frac{c^2}{e^2} + \frac{A^2}{(b+c)^2}=1$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan, i'll correct the comment.

Comment: @PierreCarre So the last equation is not independent of the others, is that right? I had a suspicion this was the case, but how does one determine this is the case?

Comment: The last equation is an universal condition. You may as well consider $0=0$ as your last equation.

Comment: Would you accept a solution where given known $\,A,D\,$ then $b$ is the solution of a quadratic equation in $\sin(\theta)\,,$ and $\,c\,$ the solution of a linear equation in $\,b,\sin(\theta)\,$ and $\,e\,$ is linear in $\,b,c,\sin(\theta).\,$?

Comment: Do you mean [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3096321/265466)? It’s helpful to potential answers to provide a pointer to it for context.